# How to implement LSTM backpropagation through time?

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network, backpropagation, derivative

I'm building a custom LSTM net based on [this](https://medium.com/@dovanhuyen2018/back-propagation-in-long-short-term-memory-lstm-a13ad8ae7a57) article. I got questions on how to implement the backpropagation, based on these formulas of the derivatives in an LSTM layer:
[image]

Question 1: The weights (w.., v.., b..) in the formulas for dHt and dXt have a T above them. Does that mean we have to use the "original" weights that have been used at that time step during propagation (and not current weights which might have been updated since then)?

Question 2: When we start backpropagation through time, where do we get dCt+1 and dHt+1 from? As we go back in time, they are accumulated (as shown in the formulas), but at the first iteration, do we just set them to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a general understanding of BPTT with LSTM units check out this numerical example:
https://medium.com/@aidangomez/let-s-do-this-f9b699de31d9

Comment: Could you explain why they use a matrix of two elements as inputs (x0[1,2], x1[0.5,3]), two W weights, and what the "with label: ..." means in relation to that? (sorry, English math is not my native)

Comment: Input x0 is the input of the first time step and x1 is the input of the second time step. Both have to elements because the example uses and input layer containing 2 input input nodes. Therefore there are two weights for each gate, corresponding to the to inputs of every time step. The label is just the target output.